# Problem with i18n urls where I'm redirected to the right url but the template is not found

Tags: django

I read on the documentation page of `i18n` the following:

```
Warning

Ensure that you don’t have non-prefixed URL patterns that might collide with an automatically-dded language prefix.
```

I don't get this warning at all, what's the meaning of it??

I'm actually having a problem where I'm directed to my `en/sitepages/news-events-listing` or `ar/sitepages/news-events-listing` by a url defined like this in the root `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("sitepages/", include("sitepages.urls")),
)
```

and I've put it before thr wagtail urls line, but the template returned by the view inside `sitepages/views.py`:

```
def sitepages_view(request):
    template = loader.get_template('sitepages/news_events_page_listing.html')
    context = {
        'news_pages': NewsDetails.objects.all(),
        'events_pages': EventsDetails.objects.all(),
        'listing_page': NewsEventsListing.objects.first(),
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

and the `sitepages/urls.py`:

```
app_name = "sitepages"

urlpatterns = [
    path("news-events-listing/", sitepages_view, name='listing'),
]
```

I can't think of anything but this warning, and that I might need to understand it to solve the problem, although I know that the order of urls in the root urls.py matter, so I might include it if anyone's think it might cause the problem but I don't want to make the question too long

> **Note**: if I replace the HttpResponse with a simple one like this `HttpResponse('Hi')` it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your simple `HttpResponse('Hi')` works but your `Response` with the rendered template is not, this has nothing to do with your i18n prefixed URLs but with the loading of the template.

Make sure the template actually exists in `PROJECT_ROOT/sitepages/templates/sitepages/news_events_page_listing.html'` and `sitepages` is listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

As an alternative, you could move the template to any app you've listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and make sure the path, starting from the `templates/` directory of that app, matches the template name you use in your view.